# Perform an LDAP search from a module

Tags: webforms, 9

I am trying to perform an LDAP search from `hook_form_validation()` in a webform using Drupal 9 and drupal/ldap 4.3.

I have configured the LDAP module on my site, but I am not using it for authentication. I can however use ldap query and perform a test of the ldap server on /admin/config/people/ldap/server successfully.

At the bottom of [API usage](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap/api-usage) they say you can use the following code.

```php
$factory = \Drupal::service('ldap.servers');
$server = $factory->getServerByIdEnabled('my_server');
```

I have been enlightend cliefen that the service is ldap.bridge.  Here is my current code.

```php
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\ldap_servers\Entity\Server;


function drp_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {
  if ( $form_id === 'webform_submission__myform_node_5930_add_form' ) {
    $userid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $username = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccountName();
    $server = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage( 'ldap_server')->load('myserver');
    $bridge = \Drupal::service('ldap.bridge');
    $bridge->setServer( $server );
    if ($bridge->bind()) {
        
        // $dn ='ou=accounts,ou=departments,dc=servername,dc=someplace';
        // $filter="(uid=xxxx1)";
        // $returnattr = array( "sn", "givenname", "mail");

    }
  }

}
```

I was able to successfully bind the ldap server.

Question: how do I actually make an ldap search, using the drupal/ldap code, inside the bridge->bind if statement?

I did not use the $factory-> code that the API mentioned.  Do I need to?

Thanks for all your help, I am struggling, but learning :)

Comment: Is that a valid service name?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! That documentation page also reads "Disclaimer: The 3.x branch still receives heavy refactoring on an on-going basis. You will need to update your custom code accordingly." and now it's on version 4. I think the service you want is now called `ldap.bridge`, but I am not writing this as an answer because I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks cilefen!  You are correct.  

I am getting closer :)

Comment: Anyone know of any example code I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's just a couple of calls missing, or at least the following works for me:

```
if ($bridge->bind()) {
    $ldap = $bridge->get() ;
    $options = [] ;
    $entries = $ldap
        ->query('', "(&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(member=$user_dn))", $options) 
        ->execute() 
        ->toArray() ;
}
```

(The query is irrelevant, of course – it comes straight from my code).